# How to convert JSON data to XML format data and download the file in javascript

Tags: javascript

CODE converting json to xml but not as required as i wanted what should i add to add those two lines and download the xml format file

```
function json2xml(json) {
var a = json;
var c = document.createElement("resources");
var t = function (v) {
    return {}.toString.call(v).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
};
var f = function (f, c, a, s) {
    c.setAttribute("tools", "http://schemas.android.com/tools");

if (t(a) != "array" && t(a) != "object") {
        if (t(a) != "null") {
            c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));
        }
    } else {
        for (var k in a) {
            var v = a[k];
            if (k == "ki" && t(a) == "object") {
                c.setAttribute("__pi", v);
            } else {
                if (t(v) == "object") {
                    var ch = c.appendChild(document.createElementNS(null, s ? "bh" : "string"));
                    f(f, ch, v);
                } else if (t(v) == "array") {
                    var ch = c.appendChild(document.createElementNS(null, s ? "ni" : "string"));
                    f(f, ch, v, true);
                } else {
                    var va = document.createElementNS(null, s ? "ki" : "string");
                    if (t(v) != "null") {
                        va.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v));
                    }
                    var ch = c.appendChild(va);
                    ch.setAttribute("name", k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
f(f, c, a, t(a) == "array");
console.log(c.outerHTML);
return c.outerHTML;
```

}

OUTPUT-

```
<resources tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<string name="app_name">translations</string>
<string name="bread">jam</string>
<string name="flew">doctor</string>
<string name="version">Version</string>
</resources>
```

Required output-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">
<string name="app_name">translations</string>
<string name="bread">jam</string>
<string name="flew">doctor</string>
<string name="version">Version</string>
</resources>
```

How to add first two lines and download the file in xml format?

Comment: for download see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add attribute on resources and insert `<?xml>` string at the start.

```
function json2xml(json) {
  var a = json;
  var c = document.createElement("resources");
  var t = function (v) {
    return {}.toString.call(v).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
  };
  var f = function (f, c, a, s) {
    c.setAttribute("tools", "http://schemas.android.com/tools");
    c.setAttribute("tools:ignore", "MissingTranslation");

    if (t(a) != "array" && t(a) != "object") {
      if (t(a) != "null") {
        c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));
      }
    } else {
      for (var k in a) {
        var v = a[k];
        if (k == "ki" && t(a) == "object") {
          c.setAttribute("__pi", v);
        } else {
          if (t(v) == "object") {
            var ch = c.appendChild(document.createElementNS(null, s ? "bh" : "string"));
            f(f, ch, v);
          } else if (t(v) == "array") {
            var ch = c.appendChild(document.createElementNS(null, s ? "ni" : "string"));
            f(f, ch, v, true);
          } else {
            var va = document.createElementNS(null, s ? "ki" : "string");
            if (t(v) != "null") {
              va.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v));
            }
            var ch = c.appendChild(va);
            ch.setAttribute("name", k);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  f(f, c, a, t(a) == "array");
  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + c.outerHTML;
  console.log(xml);
  return xml;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks alot and can you please help me with downloading the file in xml format??

Comment: <string name="app_name">Month</string><string name="session">session</string><string name="different">desktop</string><string name="version">Version</string><string name="retry">Retry</string><string name="high">high</string><string name="empty">empty</string><string name="feed">feed</string> how to formatt it?

Comment: what do you mean? XML to JSON?

Comment: but coming like this 
<string name="app_name">Month</string><string name="session">session</string><string name="different">desktop</string><string name="version">Version</string><string name="retry">Retry</string><string name="high">high</string><string name="empty">empty</string><string name="feed">feed</string> 
not aligned..

Comment: The fiddle link gives the contents as expected. What was your input?

Comment: In comments its not coming alined i will tell u i mean after downloading the xml file when text node ends it shud break the line and then print <string></string>then line break again <string></string>

Comment: You want to prettify the result.

Comment: but now the way it is, it is difficult to understand because there is no line break , u got my point Chase Choi

Comment: You should use external library for that functionality. Something like: https://gist.github.com/sente/1083506/d2834134cd070dbcc08bf42ee27dabb746a1c54d

Comment: without using  external library is it not possible by appending break or something.?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The external library is just one function. Don't be afraid to try the function.

Comment: hey need ur help for downloading multiple files by ziped it can u share ur mail id if possible ?

Comment: You cannot make zip files through client-side code only.